# SVN: locally ignore files when updating

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I would like to delete/change some file in my local SVN repository and then SVN not to try update them while doing update (just for me on my local machine). I have to test one specific bug with this customers data, but it 12GB of them. So I would like to exchange some of DB file with dummy (empty with correct structure (MDB)) files. And I want SVN to ignore these files while doing updates (especially not to bother me with conflicts).

Is this possible?

Thx, Milan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not possible. However, you can selectively update all other files.

Comment: i know i can do it selectively - but this is quite anoying :/ - anyway thx - i was just checking if i'm right and that it's not possible

Answer (score 0):

You must add the file to the parent directory's svn:ignore property.
If you're using tortoisesvn there should be a menu option to "Add to ignore list" or something similar. 
documentation link: http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-ignore.html

Comment: It's not just locally but it is kind of the correct answer, as that's the only way to do it right now. Imho it ought to be possible to do a global ignore on a single folder but it isn't right now, as the link Phil posted demonstrates.